# WPF IMultiValueConverter DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, imultivalueconverter

I have several fields
which per these fields I want to make some row in list visible or not visible
per these fields.

I am trying to work with IMultiValueConverter, however, all the values I get are {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}.

I attaching my code hope to get help
thanks for the answers.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="LVGuiCoreBus" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseDown="LVGui_MouseDown"  Grid.Row="1" >               
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConvertorVisibility}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding ElementName="Source" Path="Visibility" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Destination" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Module" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Controll" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Command" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="HSCommand" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Grid.Visibility>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>                                                      
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateNTimeStr}"  Foreground="Green" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" Foreground="{Binding Source,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" Background="{ Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConverterBySource}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Destination}" Foreground="{Binding Destination,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="4" Background="{ Binding Destination, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConvertorByDestantation}}"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Module}" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{ Binding Module, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByModule}}"   />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Controll}" Grid.Column="8"  Background="{ Binding Controll, Converter={StaticResource BackGRoundFilterByControll}}"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Command}" Grid.Column="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByCommand}}"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HSCommand}" Grid.Column="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding HSCommand, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByHsCommand}}"   />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data_Str}"  Grid.Column="14"/>                                                                
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="CMMenuCopy">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyLine" Header="Copy Line" Click="MCICopyLine_Click" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyText" Header="Copy Only Data Array" Click="MCICopyText_Click" />
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCIClear" Header="Clear" Click="MCIClear_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

Convertor Implementation:

```
public class MultiValueConvertorVisibility : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool x = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]);
        if (x)
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

C# code

```
 ObservableCollection<CStrucutreData> _LStructureGUIFile = new   
 ObservableCollection<CStrucutreData>();
 LVGuiCoreBus.ItemsSource = _LStructureGUI;
 LVGuiCoreBus.DataContext = _LStructureGUI;
```

C#  CStrucutreData:

```
public class CStrucutreData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    private string _DateNTimeStr;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string DateNTimeStr
    {
        get
        {
            return _DateNTimeStr;
        }

        set
        {
            _DateNTimeStr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateNTimeStr");
        }
    }


    private DateTime _DateNTime;

    /// <summary>
    /// DateTime in DateTime Format
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateNTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _DateNTime;
        }

        set
        {
            _DateNTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateNTime");
        }
    }




    private byte [] _Data_byte;


    /// <summary>
    /// Data in  bytes array
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Data_byte
    {
        get
        {
            return _Data_byte;
        }

        set
        {
            _Data_byte = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data_byte");
        }
    }



    private string _Data_Str;

    /// <summary>
    /// Data in string 
    /// </summary>
    public string Data_Str
    {
        get
        {
            return _Data_Str;
        }

        set
        {
            _Data_Str = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data_Str");
        }
    }


    private string _Translation;

    /// <summary>
    /// a small translation to translate Command
    /// </summary>
    public string Translation
    {
        get
        {
            return _Translation;
        }

        set
        {
            _Translation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Translation");
        }
    }


    private string _Channel;

    /// <summary>
    /// a small translation to translate Command
    /// </summary>
    public string Channel
    {
        get
        {
            return _Channel;
        }

        set
        {
            _Channel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Channel");
        }
    }


    private string _Source;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string Source
    {
        get
        {
            return _Source;
        }

        set
        {
            _Source = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Source");
        }
    }

    private string _Destination;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string Destination
    {
        get
        {
            return _Destination;
        }

        set
        {
            _Destination = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Destination");
        }
    }

    private string _Module;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string Module
    {
        get
        {
            return _Module;
        }

        set
        {
            _Module = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Module");
        }
    }

    private string _Controll;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string Controll
    {
        get
        {
            return _Controll;
        }

        set
        {
            _Controll = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Controll");
        }
    }


    private string _Command;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string Command
    {
        get
        {
            return _Command;
        }

        set
        {
            _Command = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Command");
        }
    }

    private string _HSCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Date Time in a string
    /// </summary>
    public string HSCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _HSCommand;
        }

        set
        {
            _HSCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HSCommand");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// init all variables for properties
    /// </summary>
    public CStrucutreData()
    {
        _Data_byte = new byte[1];
        _Data_Str = "";
        _DateNTime = new DateTime();
        _DateNTimeStr = "";
        _Translation = "";
        _Channel = "";
        _Source = "";
        _Destination = "";
        _Module = "";
        _Controll = "";
        _Command = "";
        _HSCommand = "";
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



}
```

Comment: You're binding to named elements but I don't see those elements in your Xaml.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you're trying to achieve with your multi-binding. You want the visibility of each item in the list to be dependent on several properties of the bound item, but your converter only looks at the first one (and will only succeed even then if the Source property is actually a boolean string representation, while your comment suggests it's some kind of date/time)? Maybe a fuller explanation of what effect you're trying to achieve will help.

Comment: the convertor is work for only 1 parameter to try work on converter when all elements will work.
the fields are bollean if true need to visisle if false need to collapsed

Comment: Are you trying to control the visibility of the entire item or each individual TextBlock inside the item? Either way, you don't currently have any booleans in your model to bind to or convert.

Comment: `Visibility` type value is not `true`/`false`, but `Visibility.Collapsed`, `Visibility.Hidden`, or `Visibility.Visible`. I do not think you can just convert it to `bool` in your converter at the first line.